# hive timezone conversion with short Timezone IDs

Tags: date, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to convert UTC time to Local Timezone. I only require the date to be extracted. When I try the below it works and gives correct results.

```
select to_date(FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp(), 'Pacific/Fiji'));
```

But if I try, short ID of the respective timezone it is giving wrong results.

```
select to_date(FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP(current_timestamp(), 'FJT'));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the difference in GMT and UTC short IDs. In the above example 'Pacific/Fiji' is a UTC based short ID where are 'FJT' is GMT equivalent. Since we are using hive function FROM_UTC_TIMESTAMP we have to use UTC based short IDs. Here is a list of [UTC based short IDs](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-date-time/java-util-timezone.html#time-zone-names-ids-and-offsets)